# How to design RabbitMQ implementation in spring api project?

Tags: spring, rabbitmq

This is going to be a declarative question. I know what is rabbitMQ and why it is used for. 
I have a spring API project that has many API endpoints. 
For example, localhost:80/do-A, localhost:80/do-B
Now, My client project creates requests with these endpoints with required parameters.
Inside my API project, the endpoints look like

```
Map(/do-1)
public Customer DoA(Customer customerObject){
return customer
}
```

As far as I know, RabbitMQ is a middleware between API and the CLIENT to store requests, and API will be able to retrieve each request one by one and this approach ensures the stability and no request loss during heavy load, especially when it comes to transactional activities.

If I implement rabbitMQ, the design will look like,

1. Client->Create request>send to rabbitMQ, Listen to rabbitMQ
2. API retrieves the request from the queue, processes it, and sends the response to the queue.

So, the question is, what should I need to do to convert my existing endpoints into the rabbit implemented endpoint? Will they still be there after rabbit implementation or I will have to change them all and attach listeners for all of them one by one?

Comment: If client project will push messages to the queue and the server listens to the same queue, i do not think you need API layer.

Comment: This is a good point that I am trying to understand. Do I need to still keep the api layer if I implement rabbit

Comment: No, You will only need to keep the service layer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to design your system around the queue, where you need to enqueue the message in any asynchronous task executor like [Rqueue](https://github.com/sonus21/rqueue) or AMQP.

In Queueing based solution you would enqueue all the payload related to API request so that you can handle them without any issues. 
For a sample case you can record like

```
class Request{
  String URL;
  Map<String, Object> body; // String
}
```

Once you enqueue this request then you need to consume these requests from the queue. Post consumption you can take all the necessary actions.

**Edit:**

Flow:

```
+------+                              +---------+
|      | ---> ==Request  Queue=== --> |         |
|Client|                              |Consumer |
|      | <--- ==Response Queue=== <-- |         |
+------+                              +---------+
```

A client would generate an API request with request Id, a consumer would consume the request from request queue, after processing, it will enqueue the response in the response queue. The response queue entry must contain the request ID apart from any other data so that client can relate a response to a request.

At very high-level entry in request-queue would look like

```
class Request{
    String id;
    String URL;
    Map<String, Object> body; // String
    // Any other fields
}
```

Response queue entry

```
class Response{
 String id;
 String requestId; 
 // Any other fields
}
```

Comment: So how my consumer will know there is a request in the queue. I mean do I need to execute my consumer method continuously or add a listener?

Comment: If you're using Rqueue it's very simple, depending on the traffic you need to increase the concurrency of the listeners.  You would need to just add a couple of lines to get this working using Rqueue. https://github.com/sonus21/rqueue

Comment: Could you please define the architecture, I mean,
Client->generate request>send it to rabbit queue
API->consumes request from queue, generate a key, send it to client, process the request, send the response to queue with the key
Client>got the key, listen on the response channel with the key
Is this the design that will be look like?